# how to start one activity for user and another activity for admin from login page

Tags: android-activity

I have a login screen activity.  From here if user is logged activity1 has to be called and if admin is logged  activity2 has to be called.  please give code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to Android activities? If so, you don't need two activities for the two situations, one is enough, what you need afterwards is a factory that will return a fragment for each situation (user or admin). You will have two fragments, one for user and one for admin, each will have its own UI and own logic, depending of what your user or admin are allowed to do.

Comment: The code used in activities is not working in fragments class.  please give some code for fragments.  how to start an activity in fragment.

Comment: Is there a solution, other than using fragments for both activities.